# проблема с установкой драйверов nvidia под ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia

пытаюсь установить проприетарный драйвер от nvidia для ноутбука dell для которого это nvidia-375 чтобы пользоваться возможностями opengl 4.x при разработке приложений

видеокарта - nvidia geforce 920m

после всяких разнообразных попыток установки драйвера в итоге после reboot а получил чёрный экран (что свиделетельствует о некорректной установке драйвера)

дабы от него избавится - следовал [этим](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) шагам (см. первый ответ) - черный экран исчез, но поставился опенсорсный nouveau драйвер вместо nvidia в котором opengl 3.3 только.

далее решил удалить все пакеты от nvidia через

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

но на всех пакетах говорит следующее

`Package 'nvidia-*' is not installed, so not removed`

вобщем вот полный вывод

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package 'libgl1-nvidia-alternatives' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-vdpau-driver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-driver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-glx' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-amd64' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-686-pae' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-486' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-313' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-313' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-319' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-325' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-325-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-325' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-331' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libgl1-nvidia-glx' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-debugger' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-compute-profiler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-profiler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-profiler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-334' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-334-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-334' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-337' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-337-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-337' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-343' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-343-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-343' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-349' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-349-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-349' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-355' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-355-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-355' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-310' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-310-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-313-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-319' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-319-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-experimental-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-173' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-173-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-310' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-310-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-310-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-310-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-313-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-313-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-310' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-310-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cg-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cg-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cg-toolkit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-gdb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-nsight' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-profiler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-visual-profiler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-prime' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-319' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-319-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-319-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-319-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-updates-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-updates-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-304-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-346-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-346-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'boinc-nvidia-cuda' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-modprobe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-settings' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'bumblebee-nvidia' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-304-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-304-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-updates-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-331' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-331' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-352-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-352-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-361-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-361' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-361' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-361' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-367-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-367' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-367' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-367' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-370-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-370' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-370' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-370' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-375-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-375' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-375' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-375' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb autogen bbswitch-dkms binutils-mingw-w64-i686
  binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 dmraid g++-mingw-w64 g++-mingw-w64-i686
  g++-mingw-w64-x86-64 gcc-mingw-w64 gcc-mingw-w64-base gcc-mingw-w64-i686
  gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 gfortran-mingw-w64 gfortran-mingw-w64-i686
  gfortran-mingw-w64-x86-64 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gnat-mingw-w64 gnat-mingw-w64-base gnat-mingw-w64-i686
  gnat-mingw-w64-x86-64 kpartx kpartx-boot libdebian-installer4
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libjansson4 libjs-jquery
  libjs-jquery-ui libopts25 libopts25-dev libvdpau1 libxnvctrl0 lvm2 mingw-w64
  mingw-w64-common mingw-w64-i686-dev mingw-w64-x86-64-dev python3-icu
  python3-pam quilt rdate screen-resolution-extra watershed
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

почему эти пакеты не могут удалится ?

делаю `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-common`

вывод аналогичный -

`Package 'nvidia-common' is not installed, so not removed`
говорит is not installed но для

`sudo apt-cache search nvidia-common`

вывод

```
ubuntu-drivers-common - Detect and install additional Ubuntu driver packages
nvidia-common - transitional package for ubuntu-drivers-common
```

что это значит ?

и ещё, почему в additional drivers `NVIDIA Corporation: Unknown` ?
с чем это связано ?

вобщем я уже незнаю что предпринять что делать ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *пытаюсь установить проприетарный драйвер* — это первая ошибка. *поставился какой то опенсорсный nouveau драйвер* — собственно, то, что и было до попыток решить несуществующую проблему. // у вас сейчас всё в порядке, не морочьте больше себе голову.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне нужно хоть какой то драйвер от нвидии установить, хоть опенсорсный хоть проприетарный, но никак не от nouveau он толком ни на что не годен для моих задач ...

Comment: у вас сейчас *опять* (как и после установки системы) стоит «драйвер» nouveau. это именно свободное программное обеспечение именно для работы с видеокартами производства nvidia. всё в порядке, больше ничего делать не надо.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тогда  почему в Details  у меня написано `Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) ` ? это ведь интегрированная в материнку видеокарта, а не geforce 920m

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне нужно использовать именно выделенную видеокарту geforece 920m а не интегрированную, для которой почему то очень медленно работают некоторые демо на webgl

Comment: я не в курсе, что такое «details», но раз у вас две видеокарты, то подключите монитор к той, которая требуется. а т.н. «драйверы» менять не стоит, особенно если вы не очень понимаете, что делаете и к чему это приведёт. *очень медленно работают некоторые демо* — это ведь совсем другой вопрос, который вы так и не задали. а вместо него задали совсем другой. классическая [проблема xy](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin такой проблемы нет, а демо не то что медленно запускаются, так некоторые вобще не запускаются, но вопрос не у меня не в этом, а в том который у меня в посте. и монитора нет, только ноут

Comment: да, обычно, тем, кто сталкивается с «проблемой xy», не нравится, когда им про это говорят. беру свои слова обратно. у вас проблема «демо либо не запускаются, либо запускаются медленно». вот про эту проблему и задайте, пожалуйста, вопрос. вполне возможно, что вам кто-то чем-то в её решении и поможет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нет у меня проблема с установкой драйверов он нвидии, а демо на данном этапе не важны

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я чётко описал проблему в вопросе, повторяю ещё раз мне необходимо пользоваться возможностями opengl 4.xxx при разработке приложений, который прибудет с драйвером от нвидии, а у nouveau opengl 3.3 только.

Comment: *у меня проблема с установкой драйверов он нвидии* — это абсолютно нормальная ситуация (ввиду ряда вполне объктивных причин, изложение которых не влезет в комментарий). *мне необходимо пользоваться возможностями opengl 4.xxx при разработке приложений, а у nouveau opengl 3.3* — вот видите, мы уже докопались до истинной проблемы. вот про неё и задайте вопрос. не забыв упомянуть, что т.н. «драйвер» от nvidia вы уже ставили (и, как часто и с ним и случается — безуспешно).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил в вопросе про опенгл, теперь что нибудь по теме скажете или по советуете ?

Comment: да, конечно, и по новой теме у меня есть что сказать: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/talks/11799984

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну незнаю я всё таки упёрто намерен поставить драйвер от нвидии

Comment: @alexanderbarakin и какие вобще гарантии что opengl 4 от nouveau выдаст ту же производительность что и от nvidia ??

Comment: мне известно лишь об одной гарантии: свободное п.о. nouveau будет работать, а с проприетарным п.о. от nvidia, как вы сами убедились, количество проблем лишь возрастает.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну у нвидии есть ещё и опенсорсные драйвера

Comment: @alexanderbarakin люди ставили себе драйвер от нвидии и я поставлю )

Comment: @ampawd, репозитории для лохов. Качни `run` файл с дровами с сайта нвидии и поставь его как истинный виндовод. @alexanderbarakin, объяснишь ему потом что такое сарказм, когда ОС окончательно улетит в трубу?